# How to get element data to debugger script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write my first chrome extension for a specific website, automatically downloading streams that are loaded by the site. I've come as far as downloading the stream using the chrome.debugger api, but now i want to auto name the stream using data on the website.

First, let me give you the relevant scripts:

```
manifest.json
---------------------------------------
{
"name": "Downloader script",
"description": "Downloads stuff",
"version": "0.1",
"permissions": [
"debugger",
"downloads"
],
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_title": "Downloader"
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

here is the background.js, it displays a window stating all the files that have been downloaded.

```
background.js
--------------------------
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.debugger.attach({tabId:tab.id}, version,
  onAttach.bind(null, tab.id));
});

var version = "1.0";

function onAttach(tabId) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    return;
  }

  chrome.windows.create(
      {url: "headers.html?" + tabId, type: "popup", width: 400, height: 600});
}
```

Here is the (very simple) headers.html that is called:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#container {
  white-space: pre;
}

.request {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

</style>

<script src="headers.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now here comes the hard part, the headers.js

```
var tabId = parseInt(window.location.search.substring(1));

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId:tabId}, "Network.enable");
  chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent);
});

window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
  chrome.debugger.detach({tabId:tabId});
});

var requests = {};


function onEvent(debuggeeId, message, params) {
  if (tabId != debuggeeId.tabId)
    return;

  if (message == "Network.requestWillBeSent") {
    var requestDiv = requests[params.requestId];
    if (!requestDiv && params.redirectResponse) {
      var requestDiv = document.createElement("div");
      requestDiv.className = "request";
      requests[params.requestId] = requestDiv;
      downloadSong(params.requestId, params.redirectResponse);
    }
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(requestDiv);
  }
}

function downloadSong(requestId, response) {
  var requestDiv = requests[requestId];
  var newSong = document.createElement("div");
  newSong.textContent = "New song is being downloaded...";
  var songLink = document.createElement('a');
  var songLinkText = document.createTextNode("Direct link to song");
  songLink.appendChild(songLinkText);
  songLink.title = "Right click -> save as...";
  songLink.href = response.headers.location;
  if (songLink.href.indexOf("//audio") > -1) {
    requestDiv.appendChild(newSong);
    requestDiv.appendChild(songLink);
    chrome.downloads.download({url: response.headers.location},function(id){});
  }
}
```

Now the website i'm taking the streams from has the following structure:

```
<div id="trackInfo" class="unselectable">
    <div class="contents" style="display: block;">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="trackData">
                <div><a href="http://www.linktowebsite" class="songTitle" address="true">This is the song title i want to grab</a></div>
                <div><i class="byText">by</i> <a href="http://www.artistlink" class="artistSummary" address="true">Artist name i want to grab</a>
                </div>
                <div><i class="onText">on</i> <a class="albumTitle" address="true" href="http://www.albumlink" style="">Album title i want to grab</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is: how can I grab the element data from the page (the DOM i believe it is called) and use it with the chrome.downloads api? Since the headers.js file is (i think) not in contact with the webpage itself, just the network part.

PS: My first time posting here, constructive criticism on my post would also be welcome.

Comment: I have a feeling you're hunting squirrel with a howitzer here; take a look at [`chrome.webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

Comment: There's a good chance of that ;) I'm just learning by modifying other example code, so this might just be done alot simpler. Still, how would I get the element data from a background.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling you're *hunting squirrel with a howitzer* here, employing `"debugger"` to intercept network requests and inject DOM into a page.

- For intercepting network requests, there's a dedicated API for that, [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

  You can attach a listener to `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, and you will have the same kind of information as you are using in your `chrome.debugger.onEvent` listener.
- For injecting your DIV and reading data from DOM, you (only) need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#contentScripts).

*The following code will assume assume you'll also use jQuery (no reason not to, it's easier to manipulate DOM with it). And it's only skeleton code.*

You can assign a content script to always load on the music service, and listen to messages from background with `chrome.runtime.onMessage`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
  if(message.songUrl){
    var newSong = $('<div>').text(New song is being downloaded...);
    /* fill the <div> and append it to the page */
  }
});
```

When your background detects music stream download, it has `tabId` from the request event, and can message the required tab:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details){
    if (details.url.indexOf("//audio") > -1) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {songUrl: details.url});
    }
    return {}; // Do not modify the request
  },
  /* filter details */
);
```

As for extracting song details, jQuery is your friend. You need to come up with a selector which will pick the element you need:

```
// Inside content script
var songName = $("#trackInfo .songTitle").text();
// etc.
```

Comment: But what if I want to be able to turn it on/off? Would I just replace the onMessage with browserAction.onClicked? Again, I'm a firsttimer here, still trying to understand what all the commands do.

Comment: Define "turn off". Not adding a download link? Just don't send a message in `onBeforeRequest`.

Comment: Well, the output to the popup i had was just for testing, i actually wanted this script to run in the background, but still be able to turn auto downloading on/off (enable/disable the entire script with a button)

Comment: I actually just noticed that you were opening a popup and not adding a div to the song page.. If you need that, you can continue opening the popup (ignore the code for building the <div>) but you can still use a content script in the song page to retrieve song data. Read on [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) for ways to return data to background.

Comment: I'm afraid your other questions are overstepping Stack Overflow's accepted format. If you have additional questions, make new questions. Be warned though, SO is not, in general, a good resource for beginners' questions. Be sure to read ["How to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in-depth first. _I'm not opposed to coaching you a bit, but it must happen outside SO; leave some contact information in your profile._

Comment: I put my email in my profile, send me an email, i'll delete it again.